# (Discord.py) Bot is able to add roles in one server, but not the othe)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot is able to add roles to other people in a test server, but not able to in my main server. They both have the same Administrative permissions and roles.

Here is my role code:

```
role = 'Customer'
await author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(author.guild.roles, name=role)) #add the role
print(f"{author} was given Customer Role.")
```

Here is the Error (Which I only get when using the command in the main server):

```
Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

At this point I think it is something in the developer panel to configure but not sure.

Comment: Have you made sure the bot role is above the customer role in both servers? Even with "Manage roles" permissions, the bot can only manage roles that are ranked lower than its own role

Answer (score 1):

Check the hierarchy. If the bot's role is underneath the role you are trying to add the bot still can't add the role even if he has the administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot does not have permission to manage roles on that server. You should wrap your code in a try-except block and have it output an error on the server when this happens. For example:

```py
role = 'Customer'
try:
    await author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(author.guild.roles, name=role)) #add the role
except discord.Forbidden:
    await ctx.send("Error! I do not have permission to manage roles!")
print(f"{author} was given Customer Role.")
```

Ask the server owner (or an administrator) to grant your bot the necessary permissions.